# Finding the initial code that is being referenced in an using directive in c# with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am working with multiple people's code and I am looking to edit some code that is being imported into the project. The using directive is:

```
using Webname.Mims.Reporting.Utilities;
```

In visual studio I tried right clicking and then selecting 'go to declaration'. Upon selection it highlighted whatever part of the word I just right clicked on instead of taking me to where the code is initialized.

Is there a way to tell visual studio that I want it to take me to the original initialization of that code instead of just the declaration for that document?

## Edit:

In order to find the initialization I had to click on the class that was referencing the using directive.

in this case:

```
        Creator creator = new Creator  //<--click on Creator
        {
            IncludeLabelBorders = false
        };
```

Then I hit F12 and it took me to a page generated from the metadata where that class's code was displayed for me.

Comment: Large projects I tend to just Ctrl+Shift+F - search the entire thing and go from there.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. There is no single place where a namespace is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`F12`: Go to definition

`Ctrl F12`: Go to Declaration.

I guess you just need try hitting `F12`

Comment: Glad it helps. Good luck with your visual studio.